# What is the likely culprit of a LCD screen that is darker on one side?

Tags: laptop, display

Today I noticed my laptop's display is darker on one side than the other. It definitely wasn't like this when before I went into work this morning, and in-between uses it was just sitting at home with the display off.

It's a mid-2007 Vostro 1500. View from a cell phone camera:

[image: laptop screen dim on left side]

It's not quite as bad as it looks from this photo, but it's really annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a dead lamp.  There's lamps that light up your LCD.  Looks like this screen has the left-most one dead.  Could be the lamp burned out, some connector to it or whatever...  Or depending on how bad, maybe just a not as bright lamp or corroded connector leading to lower voltage.

Comment: It could also be the power inverter.  With care, it's possible to disassemble the monitor and replace the broken part with an ebay'd replacement, but it's almost not worth the effort.  You might still be under warranty, so don't wait to contact tech support and get that fixed!

Comment: Not under warrenty any more. I think I'll replace it -- I've been thinking of getting a new laptop anyway so this is just a good excuse.